# Ubuntu 11.10 cannot connect to projector

Tags: 11.10, connection, projector

I install Ubuntu 11.10 into my laptop with dual-boot. In windows, I cannot output both is laptop monitor and projector. But in Ubuntu, it fail to.

Then I install Ubuntu in my pendrive with Unetbootin, and boot it with another PC, still no luck. That PC has no graphic card, so I believe it is not the graphic card issue that causes the projector to not working.

Any idea? I want to output to a projector

Comment: I should point out that 11.10 (Oneiric) is no longer supported, as it has reached End of Life.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Lenovo E535 running 12.04.
I am used to the function keys swapping out the display selection.

If you go to System Settings | Displays the secondary monitor comes up and you can configure the settings.

It wasn't as convenient at flipping the "F8" key but it worked.